# decrease complexity of password for recovery password asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

i want to decrease complexity of password for recovery password asp.net.for example if a user do the recovery, it send a random password only with numbers. not with complex characters!
and my second question is that can recovery password send old user password to his/her email again or not?
thank you

Comment: What?... Have YOU built this application or is it something downloaded? If you build it and built the password mechanics you should be able to do what ever you want when it comes to password recovery.

Comment: NO!! it is a control that exist in asp tool box! it called password recovery. and make a new password with complex characters!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend setting it up so you DON't sent new passwords over mail to the user. Instead send a link to a generated URL that is valid for a specific time from which the user can set a new password. This way you get around a lot of security issues with sending passwords to users in their mail.

Comment: ok!! how can i done that?!! 
i mean a link that expire after a specific time.

Comment: Since you use an existing control there might be ways to use that to do it. I would have a link where the user could request a password reset and enter his/her username or email. The system would then generate a hash and save that with an expiry time in a database or something like that. Then send a link to the users mail including the hash like `http://my.site/resetpassword.asp?uid=da2dsa81dsab3129837` where `da2dsa81dsab3129837`is the generated hash. If a user enters this url within the time frame permitted the user get's to enter a new password which is set for the user.

Comment: If the time for how long the link is valid has passed I would present an "invalid link" error or something like that. Also make sure that the link is only valid for ONE use. So once it has been used it can't be reused by the user or anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Sending the old password is realy bad practice and a huge security flaw in your system. Users normally reuse passwords. If anyone gets access to your database or pushes the users password recovery button your user is toost. So you have to save them as a hash with a salt. A way to let users change their password can be to send then a 1 time usable link where they can type a new password for your system.